# « Les dates de début » ou « les dates de débuts » ?

Tags: grammaire, pluriel

Dans un document que je rédige en ce moment, je m’intéresse à la définition d’une notion de « séquence de notes de musique ». Une note de musique est définie, outre par sa hauteur, par une « date de début », qui désigne l’instant où la note commence à être jouée.

Une date ne peut jamais correspondre à plusieurs débuts de notes : au diable la polyphonie.

Du coup, quand je parle de plusieurs « dates de début de note », j’ignore s’il faut employer le pluriel à « début » et à « note ». Remarquons que je ne désigne pas « les dates de début de chaque note », je parle de « dates de début[s] de note[s] » en général, sans évoquer une ou plusieurs notes, débuts ou dates en particulier : seulement la notion abstraite de plusieurs « dates de début[s] de note[s] ».

Pour donner un autre exemple, peut-être plus parlant : faut-il mettre la marque du pluriel dans la phrase :

> Comment fête-t-on les jours d’anniversaire[s] au Mexique ?

Dans ce cas, les « jours d’anniversaire[s] » se rapporte à une notion abstraite. On pourrait tout à fait dire « Comment fête-t-on un jour d’anniversaire au Mexique ? ». Dans le cas qui m’intéresse, hélas, je n’ai pas ce loisir.

Answer (score 3):

**Puis-je reformuler la question, j'ai l'impression qu'il y a plusieurs lapsus** ( mais"lapsi" fait plus savant) ? *Voilà ce que je crois comprendre* :

*... je parle de « dates de débuts ». Mais, quand bien même il y a plusieurs dates, il n’y en a qu’une par début. Aussi me demandé-je si je dois écrire « les dates de début » ou « les dates de débuts » ?*

Les dates de début de chaque règne sont celles de décès du précédent souverain. *Correct*.

Les dates de débuts de chaque règne sont celles de décès du précédent souverain. *Incorrect*, chaque règne n'a qu'un début. **C'est, je crois, le sujet de la question**.

La date du début de chaque règne est celle du décès du souverain précédent. *Correct*.

La date des débuts (ou : du début) de leurs vies est unique, puisqu'ils sont jumeaux (nés tous deux avant minuit, dans le même fuseau horaire). *Correct*.

Les dates des débuts de leurs vies sont les mêmes, puisqu'ils sont jumeaux. *Correct*.

Les dates des débuts de leurs vies (ou : de leur vie) ont toutes été marquées par le passage d'une comète différente. *Correct*, dates est au pluriel puisqu'il y en a plusieurs ; il est bien entendu que chacun n'a qu'une vie, mais le français autorise les deux formes : *ils ont tous repris leurs chapeaux, ou leur chapeau*.

Comment: C’est bien l’unicité d’un début par date qui me semble jouer ici. Et il s’avère que, dans le cas qui m’intéresse, les « dates de début » sont une notion abstraite. Je ne peux donc pas vraiment parler des « dates de début de chaque règne », seulement de « dates de début[s] de règne[s] » en général.

Comment: @Édouard: c'est exactement ce que je demandais dans mon commentaire ! Mais depuis la modification apportée à la question, c'est devenu clair.

Comment: En fait, le pluriel latin de _lapsus_ est _lapsus_, ou, si l'on insiste, _lapsūs_.

Answer (score 1):

« Les dates des débuts » étant tout à fait possible (tout comme « les dates du début » où le singulier n'est pas discutable), je ne vois aucune raison de mettre « <strike>les dates de débuts</strike> ».

Answer (score 1):

Je dirais...

**Les dates de départ des trains.** (un train ne part qu'une fois)

**Les dates de départs des navettes.** (une navette part plusieurs fois).

(mais pour les trains ce serait plus habituel avec *heure* au lieu de **date**, mais j'ai mis **date** pour coller à la question).

Sur le premier exemple on pourrait dire *Oui mais comme il y a plusieurs trains il y a plusieurs départs, quand bien même il n'y a qu'un départ par train*... mais cet argument n'est pas valable (de mon opinion), car le départ qualifie la date, non le train.