# « Les détergents de/des linges »

Tags: vocabulaire, articles, contractions, de

« Les détergents de linge » est un titre ou un sujet dans un contexte scientifique.
D'après la réponse trouvée [ici](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/7895/les-dates-de-d%C3%A9but-ou-les-dates-de-d%C3%A9buts), j'ai pensé que les deux variantes étaient correctes selon le cas :

- *Les détergents de linges* (on pense à linges comme un type ou une chose abstraite, pas définie).
- *Les détergents des linges* (ici, c'est une contraction de « de les », les linges sont spécifiés).

Que ce soit utilisé ou non comme une expression, ça m'intéresserait de comprendre en plus l'utilisation de « de » dans ce cas-là.

Answer (score 2):

Aucune des deux expressions *les détergents de linge* et *les détergents du linge* n'est utilisée.

En général, on dit simplement *les lessives* sinon, *les lessives/détergents pour lave-linge*, ou *détergents pour lavage à la main*, *détergents pour [le] linge*, *détergents pour textile*.

Comment: Ou: les détergents pour le linge.

Comment: c'était mon éssai pour translater de l'anglais "Laundry detergents". Que ça soit un titre ou un sujet.

Comment: Si c'est un titre, il est mieux peut être de dire "Détergents pour Linge" ou même "Détergents pour linges". Agréer?

Comment: Un titre de quoi ? Quel est le contexte ?

Comment: un titre scientifique, de la chimie, de la composition des détergents.

Comment: *Les détergents pour le lavage du linge*

Comment: Dans un contexte scientifique, j'utiliserais plutôt "détergents textiles" http://www.ecoconso.be/achatsverts/d%C3%A9tergents-textiles-0

Comment: @Greg Ok, mais pour éviter toute ambiguïté, je préfère laisser *pour* car le détergent n'est pas lui-même textile, contrairement à un *revêtement textile* par exemple.